# Django. How can I get next post written by the same author? (filter get_next_by_FOO?)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a blog with several users.

I want to add buttons "next post" and "previous post" to the post page, and I want them to link to the next/previous post written by the same author.

I know I can do something like:

```
<a href="/post/{{post.get_next_by_pub_date.slug}}">Next Post</a>
```

but this will link to the next post written by any author.

Can I somehow filter this by a particular author?

Or is there a better way to get url of a next/previous post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a generic function (from [django-baseclasses](https://github.com/gregplaysguitar/django-baseclasses/blob/3b8e01d0de47ea01359d003ec5bd95ed24e79e6a/baseclasses/util.py#L14)) which does what you want. It gets the next or previous item from a custom queryset (in your case filtering on author), and respects the ordering in your models `Meta` class (you will need an explicit `Meta.ordering` for it to work)

```
from functools import reduce
from django.db import models

def get_model_attr(instance, attr):
    """Example usage: get_model_attr(instance, 'category__slug')"""
    for field in attr.split('__'):
        instance = getattr(instance, field)
    return instance


def next_or_prev_in_order(instance, prev=False, qs=None, loop=False):
    """Get the next (or previous with prev=True) item for instance, from the
       given queryset (which is assumed to contain instance) respecting
       queryset ordering. If loop is True, return the first/last item when the
       end/start is reached. """

    if not qs:
        qs = instance.__class__.objects
    if prev:
        qs = qs.reverse()
        lookup = 'lt'
    else:
        lookup = 'gt'

    q_list = []
    prev_fields = []
    if qs.model._meta.ordering:
        ordering = list(qs.model._meta.ordering)
    else:
        ordering = []

    for field in (ordering + ['pk']):
        if field[0] == '-':
            this_lookup = (lookup == 'gt' and 'lt' or 'gt')
            field = field[1:]
        else:
            this_lookup = lookup
        q_kwargs = dict([(f, get_model_attr(instance, f))
                         for f in prev_fields])
        key = "%s__%s" % (field, this_lookup)
        q_kwargs[key] = get_model_attr(instance, field)
        q_list.append(models.Q(**q_kwargs))
        prev_fields.append(field)
    try:
        return qs.filter(reduce(models.Q.__or__, q_list))[0]
    except IndexError:
        length = qs.count()
        if loop and length > 1:
            # queryset is reversed above if prev
            return qs[0]
    return None
```

Use it like so:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

    def prev_by_author(self):
        qs = Post.objects.filter(author=self.author)
        return next_or_prev_in_order(self, True, qs)

    def next_by_author(self):
        qs = Post.objects.filter(author=self.author)
        return next_or_prev_in_order(self, False, qs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

I have a little issue though - the "prev_by_author" function always returns the first post created, not the previous one. "next_by_author" is working correctly. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: Try setting an ordering in your model's Meta class?

Comment: Yes! It works! Excellent, thanks you, it's awesome =)